# django: creating a model for Person who can be Writer or Actor or both

Tags: python, django, django-models

i am new to both python and Django, trying to create a database that hold general information about people, so i have this:

- a model for a Person (contain general info).
- a model for a Category that a person belongs to (a person can be in multiple categories at the same time).

each category contain its own extra data (a person who is in "Writers" category might have some books that we want to store in DB)

i thought about model sub-classing, but it seems that this will not work if a person can be in multiple categories the same time (especially dynamically)

another thought is creating profiles that have OneToOne relationship with the Person model, but i am not sure if it is the best way

what is the best/other ways to tackle this?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want each category to have a `ForeignKey` to `Person`.

Comment: well, yes, but it is more of a design issue rather than one-line-of-code change

Comment: I think the idea Marcin is getting at is that, is don't use inheritance for this. Instead, have `Writer`, `Actor`, etc. each just have a `ForeignKey` to a `Person`, like any other simple relationship.

Comment: i need the best way to save data specific to each category, i know that i should add a ForeignKey at the end, but shall i use model inhertance? if so how to deal with a person who has multiple categories? of shall i use profiles, then how to minimize the duplication of data

Comment: @AlAlBahri: This answer literally solves all of your questions. Each person will have a set holding each category they belong to. You might not like it (reasonably so - it's one solution among many), but please don't complain that this is not a solution.

Comment: This is Relational Databases 101, go with a ForeignKey relation for each category a person can be in and save yourself some headaches.

Comment: @glassman How does that differ from what I am suggesting? Or are you re-iterating?

Answer (score 1):

add `ManyToManyField(Category)` to Person class.

Django permissions in `User` model are solved the same way (via `Group` class)

edit:

you're right, I'm sorry about my useless answer.

My solution would looks like this:

```
Class Person(Model):

   @property
   def extras(self):
      extra_data = {}
      for category in self.categories.all():
          category_model_class = CATEGORIES_DATA_MAP[category.name]
          extra_data[category.name] = category_model_class.objects.filter(user=self.pk)

      return extra_data
```

... where CATEGORIES_DATA_MAP is dictionary with category/model relation map

Comment: well, i have done this already, and it is not my problem at all, please read my question again if you have time, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The multiple 1to1 rel is the way to go.

Define an ActorProfile model, a WriterProfile model etc, with each having a fk to User. Use some orm magic to load then when necessary.

It's basic that the FK is in the profile model, otherwise you'll need to add a new column on the user table each time you need a new kind of profile.

As the profiles will be probably somewhat overlapping, I'd suggest to use composition (instead of inheritance), do more profile types which store the common data, and keep the specific profiles for very specific data.

**EDIT**

Use a document-based database (mongodb?) and forget about migrations, fixed schemata, artificial joins... You have to think only about structuring the data the way you really need, but the advantages are worth considering.